# mysql query: how to select distinct based on time

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks something like this

```
|ID|TIME-|
|01|01:15|
|01|01:30|
|02|01:35|
|02|01:36|
|02|05:30|
|02|10:30|
|01|12:30|
```

What I want is to select distinct id only if they fall within the same hour mark, so the result I'm looking for is:

```
|ID|TIME|
|01|1:15|
|02|1:35|
|02|5:30|
|02|10:30|
|01|12:30|
```

TIME is in mysql date format.

how do I write this query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuminig that TIME is a timestamp or datetime

```
SELECT ID, TIME
FROM  yourtable
GROUP BY ID, floor(TIME/3600)
```

this is mysql specific

```
SELECT ID, TIME
FROM  yourtable
GROUP BY ID, TIME DIV 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.  This will give you one record for each ID, hour showing the first time value for the given hour.

```
SELECT ID, TIME

FROM  <yourtable>

GROUP BY ID, HOUR(TIME)

ORDER BY ID, TIME
```